# XPath Get the following-sibling node with local-name due to namespace changing

Tags: xml, xpath

I've looked through a couple of previous questions about how to select the following sibling but can't seem to do it when I am trying to ignore the namespace to select a following element.

This is an example XML

```
<root xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.org/">
    <foo:singers>
        <foo:singer>Tom Waits</foo:singer>
        <foo:value>4000</foo:value>
        <foo:singer>B.B. King</foo:singer>
        <foo:value>2000</foo:value>
    </foo:singers>
</root>
```

I want to get the value following a node based on its value for example the 4000 after Tom Waits.

What I have so far

```
//*[local-name()='singer' and text() = 'Tom Waits']/following-sibling::*//*[local-name() = 'value']
```

Unfortunately this isn't working for me.

I can do something like

```
//*[local-name()='singer' and text() = 'Tom Waits']/following-sibling::foo:value/text()
```

and that works but I would much prefer to be able to ignore the namespace 'foo'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close with what your have so far.
All you need is to replace `*//*` with `*` after `following-sibling`

```
//*[local-name()='singer' and text() = 'Tom Waits']/following-sibling::*[local-name() = 'value']/text()
```